# Oauth2 Google Authentication flow - Next.JS / Express

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, next.js, google-authentication

I am using a React/Next.Js Frontend and am trying to implement authentication with the Oauth2 strategy with Google.

I am very confused by the process.

Currently on the client, I have a Google sign in component that has a Client ID with in it and can retrieve an access token.

```
      <GoogleLogin
            clientId="myclientid"
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={userLogin}
            onFailure={userLogin}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
  />
```

I then have a function, which on success sends a post message to my backend with an access token, such as this:

```
export function googleAuthenticate(accessToken : string) : any{
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: "http://localhost:4000/auth/google",
        data: {
          accessToken: accessToken
        }
      })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Failure!");
        console.log(err);
    })
};
```

On the backend I am using passport, and the routes look like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import Logger from '../logger/index';

const router = express.Router();

export function isAuthenticated(req:express.Request, res:express.Response, next : any) {
    return req.isAuthenticated() ?
        next() :
        res.sendStatus(401);
 }  

  router.get('/fail', (_req:express.Request, res:express.Response) => {
    res.json({ loginFailed: true });
  });

  router.post('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile']}), (_req:express.Request, _res:express.Response) => {
    Logger.info("GET Request at Google Authentication endpoint received.");
  });

  router.get(
    '/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    (_req:express.Request, res:express.Response) => {
      res.redirect('/graphql');
    }
  );

export default router;
```

My passport module looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(passport : any, GoogleStrategy : any){
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.google.client_id,
    clientSecret: config.google.client_secret,
    callbackURL: config.google.redirect_url
  },
  function(accessToken : string, profile : Profile, refreshToken : string, cb : any) {
    return cb(null, {
      id: profile.googleId,
      username: profile.email,
      image: profile.imageUrl,
      firstName: profile.givenName,
      surname: profile.familyName,
      accessToken: accessToken,
      refreshToken: refreshToken
    })
  }
  ));
}
```

Since Next.js is a server side rendered, I am not able to use save a token. I understand I have to use a cookie. But how does this work? I cannot redirect the client browser from the express backend.

Currently I'm just seeing these 2 errors:

```
OPTIONS https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2localhost:3000%2Fdashboard&scope=profile&client_id=687602672235-l0uocpfchbjp34j1jjlv8tqv7jadb8og.apps.googleusercontent.com 405

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fbackoffice.dev.myos.co%2Fdashboard&scope=profile&client_id=687602672235-l0uocpfchbjp34j1jjlv8tqv7jadb8og.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4000/auth/google') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i think google auth will not work on localhost.
If i understand correctly in your serverside logic you can easily save your token as a cookie and then read them in   the client.

Not sure with passport, but you can do something similar to this :
(my app is working with an implementation of this code)

frontend :

```
  <GoogleLogin
        clientId="myclientid"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={userLogin}
        onFailure={userLogin}
        cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
/>
```

userLogin:

```
  async userLogin(response){
     var url = '/google-login/'+response.tokenObj.id_token
     fetch(url).then(/* i will handle response*/)
  }
```

Then in the backend you can  use `google-auth-library` to login or register.
 `server.js`:

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const GOOGLEID = "mygoogleid.apps.googleusercontent.com"
const client = new OAuth2Client(GOOGLEID);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

async function verify(userToken) {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: userToken,
    audience: "clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com",  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
   // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
   //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const userid = payload['sub'];
  return payload
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //const domain = payload['hd'];
}
```

In `server.js` a route similar to this :

```
   server.get('/google-login/:token',(req,res) => {
    const userToken =  req.params.token
    var  result =  verify(userToken).then(function(result){
      var userName = result.given_name
      var userSurname = result.family_name
      var userEmail = result.email
      /*
        Now user is authenticated i can send to the frontend
        user info or user token o save the token to session
      */
    }).catch(function(err){
      // error handling
    })
  })
```

Comment: To clarify,

on the frontend, I call the Google service and I am returned an object which contains the Access Token. I do a post from my frontend to my backend, where it verifies this access token by doing a call to the Google API. Upon success, I am supposed to send something back to the frontend, this something being a cookie?

Comment: It depends on what you need, you can set the cookies in the backend, or you can just send back the token (after the auth) and set the cookies from the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NextAuth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/) to handle this for you.
In order to test localhost you should use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your localhost server to the web and configure the given url in google platform