# Can anyone share an example of next js with passport google oauth2 integration?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If you have an example of code from any of your projects for **nextjs** using passport google oauth2, please share. There are some examples online for this using just nodejs but the mechanism of routes, middleware and callback is different with nextjs and I have not found a working example.

I have the following code but get a CORS error. I have seen youtube videos with google auth demos on localhost. The credentials I created also use localhost.

\lib\Passport.js

```
import passport from 'passport';

import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((req, id, done) => {
  req.db
    .collection('users')
    .findOne({ _id: id })
    .then((user) => done(null, user));
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
  callbackURL: process.env.WEB_URI+"/users/callback/google",
  passReqToCallback: true,
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  // User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
  //   return cb(err, user);
  // });
  console.log("profile below")
  console.log(profile)
}
));

export default passport;
```

\pages\login.js with button - "Login using Google"

```
  <Button
  variant="outlined"
  color="secondary"
  startIcon={">"}
  onClick={(event) => {
    googleLogin(event) }}
  >
    Login using Google
  </Button>
```

and the function in \pages\login.js

```
  async function googleLogin(e) {
    const res = await fetch('/api/authGoogle', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    console.log(res);
    return;
  }
```

And the \pages\api\authGoogle.js

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import middleware from '../../middlewares/middleware';
import passport from '../../lib/passport';

const handler = nextConnect();

handler.use(middleware);

handler.get(passport.authenticate("google", {
  scope: ['profile', 'email', 'openid'], 
}))

handler.delete((req, res) => {
  req.logOut();
  res.status(204).end();
});

export default handler;
```

What I do not have is code for `users/callback/google` and I am not sure what to write in it. The official passportjs example used just nodejs and hard to follow so any sample using next js will help me and others in future.

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of time struggling, I figured bits and pieces myself.

**Step 1**
For Oauth, we have to link to the provider using a button/link directly. WE cannot use a fetch api call that goes to api first.

Will not work
`await fetch('/api/authGoogle`

Will work
`href="/api/authGoogle`

**Step 2**

In api/authGoogle the passport.authenticate needs to be called.
`handler.get(passport.authenticate("google", {scope: ['profile', 'email']}));`

**Step 3**

In passport.js or wherever you have all the strategies

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
  callbackURL: process.env.WEB_URI+"/api/auth/callback/google",
  passReqToCallback: true,
},   
async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  console.log(profile)
  // add code here to check if user exists in database or create a new one
```

The way it works is /api/auth/callback/google gets passed a code (code=...) that you see in the browser url. The details are then passed from callback and available for `console.log(profile)` above.

**Step 4**

Callback file `/api/auth/callback/google` should look like this. I am just redirecting to home but you can set a browser cookie in this file. Install 'cookies' which is a very popular library if you want to do that.

```
handler.get(passport.authenticate("google"), (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': '/'
  });
  res.end();
})
```

Here passport.authenticate is repeated again but it was in step 2. Thats because the code needs to be used to get the profile information using the above line.

Comment: Hi there question for you, have you had difficulties keeping the `req.user` persistent . I am having a problem where I can authenticate, but when I try to use `swr` to `/api/user` I get undefined....

Answer (score 3):

When I was attempting to use `res.writeHead`, for some reason next-connect was hanging and the request would never resolve. I simply replaced it with the following code, and everything worked as expected:

```
res.status(302)
res.setHeader('Location', '/')
res.end()
```

Maybe this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Auth0 example online](https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial/#Recap) or [Vercel example](https://auth0.com/blog/ultimate-guide-nextjs-authentication-auth0/)

You can use [this Next.js solution](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth)

Edit: don't forget [to handle cors](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-cors/pages/api/cors.js) and [work locally in the correct way](https://auth0.com/docs/dev-lifecycle/work-with-auth0-locally)

Comment: Thanks. I have seen these links. Auth0 example online does not include social login. I have normal login and auth working already. The other 2 links use next-auth which has tons of extra stuff I dont need. Also I have installed passport.js and jwt and implemented them separately. Looking for a simple implementation of social logins and would appreciate it.

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972116/oauth2-google-authentication-flow-next-js-express) helping?

Comment: also this might do the heavy listing - including socials - https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0

Comment: I saw that link too. :). The answer says google login does not work in localhost but thats incorrect. Also, he is not using passportjs which is the most popular auth strategies library. I already installed passport so trying to implement with it. In the worst case, I will install next-auth but I have everything working except social login. next auth has more stuff and dependencies it will install but I do not need all that.

Comment: Do you know why I would get CORS error from my code posted in the question? That will solve this question.

Comment: well this is an entirely different problem then

Comment: Thats why looking for a nextjs, passportjs implementation example. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221595/discussion-between-itamar-and-kal).

Answer (score 0):

First off I do apologize for the "answer" but I am new to stack overflow and have no permissions to comment on your original question because apparently I lack reputation (silly imho) Anyways, I also am researching integration with Next.js, next-connect with Passport.js and I have also came to the conclusion that you can not use a `fetch()` or even axios request for that matter to hit the api endpoint and initiate passport.

Apparently you have to send your users directly on top of the endpoint (`/api/login`) and then when the user gets redirected back, hit another api endpoint (like `/api/login/return`) and then you are able to successfully grab the profile from the third party site.

I also receieved CORS issues when trying to do a fetch on the endpoint. I tried using the cors() npm library within next-connect as well as manually inserting the headers like so:

```
export default nextConnect()        
    .use((req, res, next) => {      
      req.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
      req.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE";
      req.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "x-access-token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
      next();
    })
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }))
```

I know this is unsafe but was just trying last resort options to get it to work. Do you know if it is "bad" to have the users hit the /api/ endpoints directly to get this to work? Really trying to figure this out and any response appreciated.

Comment: Hi, even if they hit the endpoint directly, they need a valid google/fb id to get in. I dont see any issues with using the /api directly.

Comment: Thankyou really appreciate the clarification on this @Kal