# Next.js implementing google signin with /api routes and passport

Tags: passport.js, next.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to implement Google signin in my serverless (`/api` routes) next.js app.
I'm using `@passport-next/passport-google-oauth2`, `next-connect` and `passport` packages.
I searched a lot and found a few helpful links online but I couldn't make it work, and I'm not sure about the whole flow that should happen here.
For example, I found those:

- https://github.com/andycmaj/nextjs-passport-session-auth
- https://todayilearned.io/til/nextjs-with-passport-oauth-cookie-sessions

I have `/api/auth/login` route for regular login. If login was successful, I'm setting `JWT` cookie on user response.

For Google login, I added `/api/auth/social/google` route, with the following code:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from '@passport-next/passport-google-oauth2';
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.OAUTH_GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, googleUserInfo, cb) => {
        console.log('accessToken, refreshToken, googleUserInfo');
        cb(null, googleUserInfo);
    }
));

export default nextConnect()
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        passport.authenticate('google')(req, res, (...args) => {
            console.log('passport authenticated', args)
        })
    })
```

and `/api/auth/social/callback/google` route, with the following code:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('serialize')
    done(null, user);
});

export default nextConnect()
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        passport.authenticate('google', {
            failureRedirect: '/failure/success',
            successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        })(req, res, (...args) => {
            console.log('auth callback')
            return true;
        })
    })
```

So what happens is that the user is redirected to `/auth/success` after signin to his google account, and console logs are:

```
accessToken, refreshToken, googleUserInfo
serialize
```

So my questions are:

1. When and how can I set the `JWT` cookie on the response to "login" the user?
2. Why the line `console.log('auth callback')` never runs? when it should run?
3. The same for `console.log('passport authenticated', args)`
4. How is a complete flow should look like in my app?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm still working on the full implementation, but according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861882/can-anyone-share-an-example-of-next-js-with-passport-google-oauth2-integration) it looks like the problem might be that passport.authenticate is supposed to be used as a middleware:

```
// api/auth/social/callback/google

export default nextConnect()
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .get(passport.authenticate("google"), (req, res) => {
    console.log('auth callback')
    res.writeHead(302, {
      'Location': '/auth/success'
    });
    res.end();
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not a Next.js expert but I had a similar "problem", only using other authentication method.

You see, the framework has a method that is really important in the authentication process, they are called: **getInitialProps**, which is an async function that can be added to any page as a static method to trigger before the initial render;

it looks like this:

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
    const json = await res.json()
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
  }
```

It takes this **ctx** prop, which is a object with {req, res} that you can use to make your request to authenticate the user and, then, you may use **req** with the lib **next-cookies** to get the JWT token and check if it is valid and, then, you may return an object, which will be used as a prop of your page (or all the pages, if you wrap your **_app.js** around a Context of Authentication.

Also, your **'auth callback'** is not being called because you redirect the user before it triggers, which is not happening. The same for **'passport authenticated'**

This article may also help you.
https://dev.to/chrsgrrtt/easy-user-authentication-with-next-js-18oe

Comment: Thanks! But the whole system is already up and runnnig. Regular (email ,pass) authentication process already works. I indeed using `getInitialProps` to check if user is authenticated, etc etc. But I don't get how can I add the option to signin with google. My problem here is not regular next.js authentication, but implementing a google sign in.